# okay, what about the pictures on my SD card?

Tags: sd-card

Will I be able to see my pictures on my home computer if they've been on an encrypted SD cell phone card? If that answer is no, that means I won't be able to use my SD card to make any prints of my pictures, correct?  If that's the case, how do I unencrypt my SD card? Or how do I change the setting for saving my pictures to my SD card? If I do this, how can I ever make prints of any of my pictures? I admit I take many family pics bc no one lives close by ~ 
it would be so nice to see some of them framed and around the house instead of only getting to look at them while sitting at the computer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question -- if your SD card is encrypted, then it won't be readable on a computer, print kiosk, or other device unless that device has compatible encryption capability and you supply the key (not going to happen at the print kiosk at Target, sorry to say).

As far as I know, there's no feature given to decrypt an entire storage volume (like your SD card); the most practical way to get the images decrypted would be to copy then to an unencrypted storage device.  One way to do that would be to install a cloud storage app (like Dropbox) on your phone.  Don't encrypt the cloud storage, and anything you copy to the cloud will be accessible to any device that has access to that cloud storage.  Dropbox has an application for Windows, Mac, and Linux, as well as both Android and iOS, which makes it a good choice (and it's free, with a fairly large storage limit, at least as of September 2017).  Some printing services will allow you to print from Dropbox storage, at least via their web page (Staples and Office Max/Office Depot allow this, as I recall).

Unless you also shoot porn on your phone or have a high enough profile to be concerned about blackmail, I don't see a lot of reason to encrypt storage of family photos anyway -- you might consider backing up your SD card (connecting the phone to a computer via USB cable may allow doing this without requiring the computer to deal with the encryption) and reformatting the SD storage without encryption.

Depending on your Android version, it may not be possible to store data (pictures, music, documents, etc.) on the SD card without adopting it, which encrypts it for unique access only by the adopting device.  If you're running Android 6 (Marshmallow) or newer, this might be the case (I can't check on my own device, as I have a Pixel which doesn't have an SD card slot).

Comment: On another hand, encryption can be an efficient countermeasure in case your device is stolen.

Comment: Seems like overkill for family photos, though, unless you're a celebrity whose family photos might be worth thousands to a tabloid.  Most people simply don't have anything that warrants encryption, truth be told.

Comment: Outside the scope of photos, we could say that almost everyone saves their contacts on their device. Personally, I won't be too happy that my contacts leaked into the hands of a random person who might have a way to use them for their own gain.

Comment: Contact, however, are usually on the device's internal storage, rather than the SD card.

Comment: Indeed, but I don't think that one can encrypt only one of the storages. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: It likely depends on the version of Android you're running.  I'm pretty sure it's possible with 4.*, but not with 6+ (which "adopt" the SD card to appear as part of internal storage).  Further, it's not possible to store anything on an SD card with 6+ without encrypting it, due to the "adoption" process.

Comment: It should be noted that adopting the SD card be optional, though. Edit: Android 7.1.2 doesn't mention the SD card at all when inside the encryption window, so it seems that, as you said above, the only way to encrypt a SD is to adopt it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Zeiss Ikon pointed out](/a/182619/16575), there's no easy way to read the encrypted card *directly* on any other machine than the one having encrypted it (here: your Android device).

However, that does not mean you cannot transfer them to e.g. your computer or a print kiosk – it only means you cannot simply take the card and plug it into another machine. As long as the card is inside your (running) Android device, its content can be accessed in multiple ways:

- plug in an USB cable and access the data via [mtp](/questions/tagged/mtp). This is the most common method, and also the intended use for "consumers" (i.e. you). Most computers should support that out-of-the-box, whether they run Linux or Windows (AFAIK also Mac). At the moment, just be careful doing that with Windows-10 due to a current bug that could delete your data instead of moving it.
- plug in an USB cable and use [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to access your data. This is mostly intended for developers, but in my experience works more stable than MTP (and has many end-user use-cases beside data copying, too). You'll need special software for that on your computer, though – please consult our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info) for details.
- install some "server software" on your Android device to access its data wirelessly. Examples are [FTP Server](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_ftp#group_408) or other apps to [Remotely manage media and files](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement#group_808).¹ The latter are often used easily with a web browser from any computer.

I'm not sure what mode might be supported by print kiosks – but all the above definitely works with computers, laptops and other network-enabled devices. Though your storage remains encrypted, it's your Android device that (decrypts and) reads the files, and then finally makes them available to "the other end".

As initially said, there are no easy ways to *directly* access the data from the card (e.g. using a card reader). So keep that in mind also for another case: If your Android device no longer starts up. With an unencrypted card, you then could simply take it out and access it via card-reader. That would no longer be possible with the card encrypted. So make sure to regularly [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) your data!

---

¹ <sub>Disclosure: Those links go to my website with Android app listings</sub>